# The code is running but there is not output showing

Tags: python-3.x

The code is being executed but the output is not shown nor the variables are created

```
import numpy as np
def magicsquares():
    n=input('enter the order of squares')
    n=int(n)
    m=np.zeros((n,n))
    s=n*(n**2+1)/2 #sum of each row or diagonal
    p=int(n/2)
    q=(n-1)
    for i in range(n**2):
        m[p][q]=1       #assigning postion of 1
        P=p-1
        Q=q+1
        if(i>=2):       #assigning remaining positions
            if(P==-1):
                P=n-1
            if(Q==n):
                Q=0
```

Comment: you can print a variable to console using `print(<name of variable>)`. If you don't explicitly call `print()` nothing gets printed. You also need to call the function `magicsquares()` after defining it. So add `magicsquares()` to the end of your code

Answer (score 0):

**there is not output showing** because you are just **declaring** the *function* but **not calling** the *function* and there is no `print`/`return` inside the *function*. Here is a solution which you can use to see the output and work on:

```
import numpy as np

def magicsquares():
    n = input('enter the order of squares')
    n = int(n)
    m = np.zeros((n, n))
    s = n*(n**2+1)/2    # sum of each row or diagonal
    p = int(n/2)
    q = (n-1)
    for i in range(n**2):
        m[p][q] = 1     # assigning postion of 1
        P = p-1
        Q = q+1
        if i >= 2:  # assigning remaining positions
            if P == -1:
                P = n-1
            if Q == n:
                Q = 0
    print(m)

magicsquares()
```

**It is not the ultimate solution to find *magic_square*. It's just an updated version of your code so that you can see the outputs and work on.**